# NullPointerException reading from InputStream

Tags: java, sockets, client, serversocket

I am developing a Client-Server game and all the steps are based on sending a request from the client and, after that, receiving a response from the server.
Sometimes receiving asynchronous messages is needed so I open a thread in the client which is listening for these messages.

The class Broadcaster:

```
public class BroadcastReceiver implements Runnable {
    private ClientController clientController;
    private AtomicBoolean running = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private Thread receiver;

    public BroadcastReceiver(ClientController clientController) {
        this.clientController = clientController;
    }

    public void start() {
        receiver = new Thread(this);
        running.set(true);
        receiver.start();
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return running.get();
    }

    public void stop() {
        running.set(false);
    }

    public void restart() {
        if (!receiver.isAlive()) {
            this.start();
        } else
            System.err.println("Thread already running");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Response response;
        do {
            response = clientController.getClient().nextResponse();
            if (response != null) {
                response.handle(clientController);
            } else
                running.set(false);
        } while (running.get());
    }
}
```

This is the code of the Client which reads and writes requests/responses

```
package ingsw.controller.network.socket;

import ingsw.controller.network.commands.Request;
import ingsw.controller.network.commands.RequestWoResponse;
import ingsw.controller.network.commands.Response;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {
    private final String host;
    private final int port;
    private Socket connection;
    private ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;
    private ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;

    public Client(String host, int port) {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void connect() throws IOException {
        connection = new Socket(host, port);
        objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        objectInputStream.close();
        objectOutputStream.close();
        connection.close();
    }

    void request(Request request) {
        try {
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(request);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Exception on network: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    void request(RequestWoResponse requestWoResponse) {
        try {
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(requestWoResponse);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Exception on network: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    Response nextResponse() {
        try {
            Response response = ((Response) objectInputStream.readObject());
            return response;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Exception on network: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Wrong deserialization: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

and finally this is the server part, a ServerController that does handle every request and returns a response (for the sake of brevity i cannot post every class here since the project is pretty long and complicated)

```
    package ingsw.controller.network.socket;

import ingsw.controller.network.Message;
import ingsw.controller.network.commands.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.List;

public class ClientHandler implements Runnable, UserObserver {
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private final ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;
    private final ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;
    private boolean stop;

    private ServerController serverController;

    public ClientHandler(Socket clientSocket) throws IOException {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        this.objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        this.objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        this.serverController = new ServerController(this);
    }

    /**
     * Method that receives every Request sent by the user and passes them to the ServerController
     * and then waits for the Response given by the ServerController and handles it
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            do {
                Response response = ((Request) objectInputStream.readObject()).handle(serverController);
                if (response != null) {
                    respond(response);
                }
            } while (!stop);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Handle Excpetions
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method that serializes objects and sends them to the other end of the connection
     * @param response response to send
     */
    private void respond(Response response) {
        try {
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(response);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getSimpleName() + " - " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        stop = true;
    }

    /**
     * Method that closes ClientHandler connection
     */
    public void close() {
        stop = true;
        if (objectInputStream != null) {
            try {
                objectInputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Errors in closing - " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        if (objectOutputStream != null) {
            try {
                objectOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Errors in closing - " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        try {
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Errors in closing - " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /*
    *
    * USER OBSERVER METHODS
    *
   */

    @Override
    public void onJoin(int numberOfConnectedUsers) {
        respond(new IntegerResponse(numberOfConnectedUsers));
    }

    @Override
    public void sendMessage(Message message) {
        respond(new MessageResponse(message));
    }

    @Override
    public void receiveDraftNotification() {
        //TODO implement first draft notification from server (button on the view)
    }

    @Override
    public void sendResponse(DiceNotification diceNotification) {
        //TODO send the list of dice (for now only the drafted dice)
    }

    @Override
    public void sendResponse(CreateMatchResponse createMatchResponse) {
        respond(createMatchResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public void activateTurnNotification(List<Boolean[][]> booleanListGrid) {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

The problem I'm getting here is that, after running the Broadcaster, which simply reads from inputstream as many times as I desire, it seems that I cannot read from inputstream with a nextResponse() method.

The order in which methods are called is Login, turn on the broadcaster, create a match and finally the join match (that throws an exception).

In this method

```
@Override
public boolean joinExistingMatch(String matchName) {
    broadcastReceiver.stop();
    generalPurposeBoolean = false;
    client.request(new JoinMatchRequest(matchName));
    client.nextResponse().handle(this);

    return generalPurposeBoolean;
}
```

I get a NullPointerException when I'm trying to handle the client.nextResponse(), I've debugged the app many times and it seems like the input stream can't properly read from the stream after running the BroadcastReceiver.

This is the thrown excpetion:

```
    Exception on network: invalid type code: 00
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$48(GtkApplication.java:139)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ingsw.controller.network.socket.ClientController.joinExistingMatch(ClientController.java:60)
    at ingsw.view.LobbyController.onJoinPressed(LobbyController.java:129)
    ... 58 more
```

Is there an explanation to this?

Comment: So, you've tested the variables on the offending line, right? Which one is null? client? Probably not since the prior line didn't throw the exception (or did it?), `client.nextResponse()`? possibly so -- so have you looked back into the code to see why?

Comment: The stack trace gives the source line number on which the exception occurs.  Only you can map line number to line.  Probably, however, one of `broadcastReceiver`, `client`, or `client.nextResponse()` is `null`.  My bet would be on the last of those.

Comment: I note, moreover, that `ingsw.controller.network.socket.Client.nextResponse()` will totally return `null` in the event that it catches an `IOException` or `ClassNotFoundException`: it just eats those exceptions and falls through to return `null`.  If that's the way you want to play it, then users of that method must be prepared for a `null` return value.

Comment: The error occurs in the last method joinExistingMatch() but it's a strange behaviour. The response that is going to be read by the latest client.nextResponse() is ok in the clientHandler and is sent correctly to the network but the inputstream in the nextResponse() method does not read it properly or does not read it at all and I don't know why.

Comment: @JohnBollinger the problem is that it should read the response in that case, cause I'm returning a response on the serverside, and nextResponse() should read it correctly but it does not

Comment: The strange thing is that if I don't call the BroadcastReceiver at all the program does run fine